# Finding one specific combination of sums out of multiple xml files

Tags: python, xml, loops, combinations

I try to find one specific sum that is made up from the IDs found in 3 different xml files.
The sum will always be unique, not other 3 element values from the xml files will add up to that sum.

My xml files look like this:

File for Fruits:

```
...
-<Fruits>
<FruitID>1000</FruitID>
...
</Fruits>
...
```

File for Country of origin:

```
...
-<Country>
<CountryID>2000</CountryID>
...
</Country>
...
```

File for corporation:

```
...
-<Corporation>
<CorporationID>5000</CorporationID>
...   
</Corporation>
...
```

This is my python code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request as ur

url_fruits = 'fruits-url\fruits.xml'
url_countries = 'countries-url\countries.xml'
url_corporations = 'corporations-url\corporations.xml'

fp_fruits = ur.urlopen(url_fruits)
tree_fruits = ET.parse(fp_fruits)
fruits = tree_fruits.getroot()

fp_countries = ur.urlopen(url_countries)
tree_countries = ET.parse(fp_countries)
countries = tree_countries.getroot()

fp_domain = ur.urlopen(url_corporations)
tree_domain = ET.parse(fp_corporations)
corporations = tree_corporations.getroot()


result = None
ID_userinput = input('What ID should be translated to fruit id?')

if ID_userinput == '':
    pass
else:
    for child in (fruits,countries, corporations):
        if int(ID_userinput) == int((child.find('FruitID').text) + (child.find('CountryID').text) + (child.find('CorporationID').text):
            result = child.find('FruitID')
        else:
            pass

print(result)
```

This always yields an error.
I don't find anything on correct syntax for iterating through multiple xml files and all the possible combinations at the same time.
Is there a solution to this?

Thanks and best regards,
Stefan

Comment: What error? Is it that you don't seem to have defined `fruits`, `countries` and `corporations`?

Comment: Sorry, I posted incomplete sample code. My live code actually works fine (my live code does alot more then the above, but with all the same objects) The line that throws the error is the for-loop in the code above. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
I guess this is because the loop-syntax is just wrong, but I can't find a way to do it correctly.

Comment: Still looks incomplete - you assign to `result` but do nothing with that variable (and there are missing imports, but we can infer what they should be)

Comment: The answer is going to be something along the lines of `child` is either your fruits document, _or_ your countries document, _or_ your corporations document, so won't contain all of `FruitID`, `CountryID` and `CorporationID`. But a more complete example will still help us provide a useful answer - please include the error output you get.

Comment: That is actually all the code  that is in this .py-file. The exact error line is as follows: `if int(ID_userinput) == int((child.find('FruitID').text) + (child.find('CountryID').text) + (child.find('CorporationID').text):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: I just want to print the result.
I only need a tool to find the fruitID  that is part of all the components that make up the final ID.
So if I enter the final ID 8000 the script should return ('print' just for now) the FruitID 1000.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what's going on here, lets unroll your loop:

```
for child in (fruits,countries, corporations):
    if int(ID_userinput) == int((child.find('FruitID').text) + (child.find('CountryID').text) + (child.find('CorporationID').text):
        result = child.find('FruitID')
    else:
        pass
```

Also, getting rid of the useless `else`, that gives us:

```
if int(ID_userinput) == int((fruits.find('FruitID').text) + (fruits.find('CountryID').text) + (fruits.find('CorporationID').text):
    result = fruits.find('FruitID')
if int(ID_userinput) == int((countries.find('FruitID').text) + (countries.find('CountryID').text) + (countries.find('CorporationID').text):
    result = countries.find('FruitID')
if int(ID_userinput) == int((corporations.find('FruitID').text) + (corporations.find('CountryID').text) + (corporations.find('CorporationID').text):
    result = corporations.find('FruitID')
```

Let look at the first of those `if` statements:

```
if int(ID_userinput) == int((fruits.find('FruitID').text) + (fruits.find('CountryID').text) + (fruits.find('CorporationID').text):
```

What is `fruits.find('CountryID')` going to give you? Does your fruits document contain country ID? If not, this would explain why you are getting `None` (and then an error when you try to access `.text` on it)

What you need instead is nested loops over each type of ID.

Something like:

```
for fruit_id in fruits.iter('FruitID'):
    for country_id in countries.iter('CountryID'):
        for corporation_id in corporations.iter('CorporationID'):
            if int(ID_userinput) == int(fruit_id.text) + int(country_id.text) + int(corporation_id.text):
                result = fruit_id
```

And there are many ways to improve that further - you can probably exit all those loops at the first result you find, instead of iterating over all the remaining combinations, for example.